# Basic mathematical induction regarding inequalities

Tags: induction

These are just the examples from my textbook, but I don't think it did not explain well.

One of the problem was to prove the inequality

$$n<2^n$$

for all integers $n$.

I understand we assume if $P(n)$ is true, $P(k+1)$ is true.

Thus $k+1< 2^{k+1}$

But in the text book, they added one more line that I don't understand:

$$k+1<2^k+1 \le 2^k+2^k=2\cdot2^k=2^{k+1}$$

I understand 
$$k+1<2^{k+1}$$

But how do I know $2^k+1$ is larger than $k+1$, and smaller than $2^{k+1}$?

I have one another example just in case,

proving $2^n<n!$ using induction.

$$2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k<2\cdot k!<(k+1)k!=(k+1)!$$

I understand we should start with $2^{k+1}<(k+1)!$, but

Where did $2\cdot k!$ come from? Textbook says it came from inductive hypothesis, but I still don't get it.

Please advise.

Comment: Do you remember that the first step in an inductive proof is testing the base case (that is, verifying the hypothesis holds for some starting value, usually $1$, the first natural number, sometimes $0$)?

Comment: Yes. That comes out when $k=1$, $1<2^1$, right?

Comment: Right. Also for $k=0$ there is $k = 0 <1 =2^0 = 2^k$. That *might* be useful if you decided to run the induction into negative numbers, too (the exercise says 'for all integers', not 'for all positive integers').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $$k < 2^k$$
add one to both sides, we get $$k+1 < 2^k + 1$$

But we also know that $2^k + 1 < 2^k + 2^k$ since $1 < 2^k$ for every natural $k$. This means we have $$2^k + 1 < 2^{k+1}$$ which completes our induction.

So, to answer your question, you need to know that $2^k > 1$ for every natural k, so that $2^k + 1 < 2^{k} + 2^{k}$. This technique comes up often in inductions using inequalities.

---

For your next example, assume $$2^k < k!$$
We have that $$(k+1)! = (k+1)k!$$

But we assumed that $2^k < k!$ so we have $$2\cdot 2^k < (k+1)k!$$
(I'm making the assumption that $n \geq 4$) and hence $$2^{k+1} < (k+1)!$$
completing our induction.

Comment: For $1<2^k$, did you mean the base case of $1<2^1$?

Comment: I still don't get the point how do we know $2^k+1<$2^(k+1)

Comment: No, I meant that we have $2^k > 1$ for every natural $k$. So, whatever $k$ you put it, you get $2^k > 1$. So, $2^2 > 1, 2^3 > 1, 2^4 > 1, etc...$

Comment: And it also says <=... so confused. Am I not knowing some basic pre-calculus here? I'm so sorry if I am not.

Comment: <= is the same thing in this case, don't worry about that.

Comment: For the first example, can I say that because we know that $1<2^k$, than we can add $2k$ on both sides so that we get $2^k+1<2^k+2^k$? I was reading it over and over the answers and this is what I got.

Comment: Sure, that's pretty much what I'm saying, just in the opposite order. Although you need to add $2^k$ not $2k$.

Comment: Oh sorry that was my mistake I was little excited. I think now I perfectly got the first one.

Comment: Great, do you need clearing up for the second part? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25532/discussion-between-zain-patel-and-minjae).

Comment: I don't get this part: $2⋅2k<(k+1)k!$. Seem like you multiplied 2 on the left side and (k+1) on the right side..

Answer (score 2):

You need to prove that $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$. So you take an arbitrary $n$ and suppose P(n) true. This gives you that

$$n < 2^n$$

You add one to each side, and you get

$$n+1<2^n+1$$

Now, you know that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, 2^n \geq 1$, hence

$$n+1<2^n+1 \leq 2^n+2^n = 2^{n+1}$$

And this is exactly P(n+1)

Answer (score 2):

> But how do I know $2^k +1$  is larger than $k+1$

Because your inductive step starts from the assumption that the given statement holds for $k$, which means $$k < 2^k$$ When added $1$ to both sides it results in $$k+1< 2^k +1$$